# Synchronise Table Data every particular time interval SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a online Database which will be updated Daily from various Sources.

I need to have a local Database with some tables from Server Database which have to check for any changes or new rows in tables in server and update the local Database for particular Intervals of Time. How can I Achieve this???

Comment: cant say but anyway my 2 cents, is this you are looking out for? http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Replication will manage the data synchronization between the two copies of your database.  You can configure replication for any tables in the database, including all tables.  Replication will take care of checking for updates, adds and deletes from the Server Database and transfer the changes to the local database.

You can setup replication to update the local database at near-real-time or you can schedule periodic updates.

Replication is a high-maintenance solution.  It's designed to maintain two copies of the same database with significant reliability.  This makes replication a good solution when you must avoid data problems or recover from problems with little to no data loss.

If you don't require the high-maintenance solution, then SQL Server Integration Services ([SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) may be a good alternative.  With SSIS, you develop the data transfer and data management solution.  Along with managing data problems, you design the solution to identify data adds, deletes and updates.

Comment: I'm trying to make a WPF application which when opened have to check for any changes in the server table and if so update in the local table. Is this possible using Replication. The application will be minimized and it has to be periodically checking for new rows in table and insert in the local Database. Is this possible ?? And you mentioned high-maintenance. what do you mean by that? can you elaborate.

Comment: Or are there any third party tools which run in background and periodically checks for new rows and inserts in the local table ??

Comment: I'm using a Shared Server for the Server Database. I just knew that the replication is not possible from a Shared Server. So can you advice me an another method in which only the local system cam get the Data ??? Thank You